# Firebase .indexOn not ordering in db

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my Firebase db

```
- "some user id"
   - "time"
       - "id for data"
          - "time data was created"
```

I have tried a variety of rules (below are my current rules) but regardless of what I do the data is ordered and retrieved by "id for data" not time.  In my app I am using

```
self.rootRef.child(uidOtherProfile).child("time").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in ..... }) to get the data.
```

My question is "am I making a mistake on the server/rules side or am I making a mistake with by not using .orderbyChild (in swift) and if I need to use .orderByChild what is the purpose of server side rules.

PS: My current rules

```
{
     "rules": {
       ".read" : "auth !== null",
       ".write": "auth !== null",
           "$groupid" : {
                       "time" : {
                       ".indexOn" : "date"
                    }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Data will only be order if you call `queryOrdered(byChild: "date"`. In your handler/block, be sure to then loop over the children, like shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Comment: First, thank you for the reply!  May I ask then, what is the purpose of the .indexOn on the rules side/wouldn't not having the data ordered until a query is made choke at scale?  Like in there are 1000 segments of data and I want the most recent ten I don't want to sort all 1000 each call.

Comment: It's the same as defining an index in any database: having an index allows efficient sorting. But you still have to tell the query to be sorted.